# Call fetch in sveltekit endpoint

Tags: sveltekit

if i call `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/verify")` POST in endpoint, i got `FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/verify failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000`.
Is there a way do likt that? I cant fetch in endpoint

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: The endpoint should work in `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your api is in your svelte app, I believe your connection address should be "/api/verify" leave the localhost stuff out.